# How use function ref inside swiper slide

Tags: vuejs3, swiper.js, ref, vue-composition-api

I am trying to use function ref inside swiper slide, but get duplicated results.

```
<swiper-slide>
    <first-step :ref="(el) => { steps.push(el)}" />
</swiper-slide> 
<swiper-slide>
   <second-step :ref="(el) => { steps.push(el)}" />
</swiper-slide>

setup(){
   const steps = ref([]);
   return { steps}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Vue document](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs), when using function refs, the bound function will be called every time component is updated. And component is being updated many times during its lifetime, that why some els are duplicated.

To prevent duplication, I think you should create multiple refs instances and combine them by a `computed` like this.

```
<swiper-slide>
    <first-step ref="firstStepRef" />
</swiper-slide> 
<swiper-slide>
   <second-step ref="secondStepRef" />
</swiper-slide>

setup(){
   const firstStepRef = ref(null);
   const secondStepRef = ref(null);
   function getEl(elRef) {
      if (!elRef.value) return null;
      return elRef.value.$el;
   )
   const steps = computed(() => {
      return [getEl(firstStepRef), getEl(secondStepRef)];
   }
   return { steps}
}
```

`ps: above code is not well-tested yet.`